# Gstreamer + OpenCV h264 Encoding&Decoding İmage Deformation Problem

Tags: opencv, video, gstreamer, h.264, v4l2

Hardware:
Apalis IMX8 CPU(SOM)
and
Sensoray model-1012 video frame grabber

I am trying to save analog video with h264 coding and play it.
The code has 3 parts. Reading camera, saving video with coding and playing video with decoding.

The problem i am facing is on decoding part. When i decode and show video it corrupts.

**How i read analog video(Works fine):**

```
cap = cv::VideoCapture(" v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)720, height=(int)480, framerate=30/1, interlace-mode=interleaved ! deinterlace fields=1 method=2 ! videoconvert ! appsink ",cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

**How i compress and save video(Works fine):**

```
cv::VideoWriter fixedVideo;
QString pipeTmp =  "appsrc ! videoconvert ! v4l2h264enc ! h264parse ! qtmux ! filesink location="+ FixedIMG_recordName +" sync=false ";
std::string pipe = pipeTmp.toUtf8().constData();
isOpen = fixedVideo.open(pipe , cv::CAP_GSTREAMER, (double)30, cv::Size(720,480), true);
```

**How i decode and open video(**DOESNT Work Fine**):**

```
cv::VideoCapture cap_reader;
QString pipeTmp = " filesrc location=" + device + " ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, width=720, height=480 ! v4l2h264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink ";
std::string pipe = pipeTmp.toUtf8().constData();
cap_reader.open(pipe , cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

when i open cap_read pipe line to play same video from **gstreamer command line** pipe it works fine with some warnings. I put the GST_DEBUG output in [log.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Agm0uDEJWrqrcw4e1Q2aMOtxGak) Pipe line:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! 'video/x-h264, width=720, height=480, framerate=30/1' ! v4l2h264dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

When i open the video from VLC it also works fine. But when i open the video from VideoCapture and the pipeline that i gave above it corrupts. The corrupted [image example](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Agm0uDEJWrqrdFSKobNYacL0UGY).
[image: Corrupted image example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in compression. When you decode mp4 file, you should use "imxvideoconvert_g2d".

Decode pipeline should be  filesrc location=" + device + " ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, width=720, height=480 ! v4l2h264dec ! imxvideoconverter_g2d ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=720,height=480 ! videoconvert ! appsink

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).